# R: How to get the right resolution (raster) by overplotting a map with raster in base R plot?

Tags: r, raster

I want to overlay a choropleth map (created in base R plot):

[image]

code:

```
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(raster)

GERblue_iran <- structure(list(veggies = c(NA, 1135142.7169744, 1064475.14405642, 
579007.139090945, 2291173.06203667, 1609487.86612194, 5514745.42173307, 
210033.193615536, NA, 1082275.82518455, 395053.664034339, 833546.886449334, 
1350410.79594876, 2030498.45168616, 5018327.9046678, 413119.296060151, 
853322.135586823, 2136776.14200603, 581494.047168068, 535593.624579909, 
414310.523642145, NA, NA, 2156369.86690811, 274390.590608389, 
546804.909031463, 144406.95766963, 285002.432443622, 1605244.30546598, 
307546.827903725, 589330.238261654), state = c("Alborz", "Ardebil", 
"Bushehr", "Chahar Mahall and Bakhtiari", "East Azarbaijan", 
"Esfahan", "Fars", "Gilan", "Golestan", "Hamadan", "Hormozgan", 
"Ilam", "Kerman", "Kermanshah", "Khuzestan", "Kohgiluyeh and Buyer Ahmad", 
"Kordestan", "Lorestan", "Markazi", "Mazandaran", "North Khorasan", 
"Qazvin", "Qom", "Razavi Khorasan", "Semnan", "Sistan and Baluchestan", 
"South Khorasan", "Tehran", "West Azarbaijan", "Yazd", "Zanjan"
)), .Names = c("veggies", "state"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
31L))

iran2 <- getData("GADM", country = "IRN", level = 1)
iran2$veggies <- GERblue_iran[,1]
iran2$veggies[is.na(iran2$veggies)] <- 0
cols <- brewer.pal(n = 4, name = "PuBu")
# jenks
lcols2 <- cut(iran2$veggies,
             breaks = classIntervals(iran2$veggies, n=7,style='jenks')$brks,
             labels = cols)
x11()
plot(iran2, col = as.character(lcols2))
```

This map should be overlay by this RasterLayer (sorry to big to attach):
[image]

For that I want to make some parts transparent and I set values below 700 to NaN (as NA didn't be transparent). Resulting in this:

[image]

As you can see single values are plotted in the bottom part of the map. However, the size (or resolution) of the dots/pixels is very coarse compared to the original raster (this occur also if I just plot without NaN and transparency). Does anyone know how to set the resolution wright in order to have the original size? Thanks

Here the code with both plots:

```
plot(iran2, col = as.character(lcols2)); plot(nut_iran2, add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can make your example much simpler:

```
library(raster)

iran <- getData("GADM", country = "IRN", level = 1)
r <- raster(iran, nrow=100, ncol=100)
set.seed(-99)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
r <- mask(r, iran)
r[r < 0.99] <- NA
```

And here is how you can make the plot:

```
plot(r)
plot(iran, col = rainbow(6, start=0.5, end=0.65), add=TRUE)
plot(r, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)
```

Because raster plotting uses a legend you may need to set up the plot area first. But you can also do

```
plot(iran, col = rainbow(6, start=0.5, end=0.65))
plot(r, add=TRUE)
```

or

```
plot(iran, col = rainbow(6, start=0.5, end=0.65), axes=TRUE)
plot(r, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I think you understand the question wrong. The choropleth was fine as it was (your version delivers a wrong picture and is unclassified).  By rsel you mean probably raster, wright. However, my problem is that by overplotting the raster, the raster gets a coarse resolution that is not as I just plot the raster alone. My question is why is this so? And how can I adjust the raster resolution to the choropleth map.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't really understand that rsel = r. The plotting this way works fine. However, my real problem with the raster resolution was, that I masked Iran from a world raster instead of first crop it to iran extent and then mask them. Therefore I get in the final plot hugh pixels as shown in my result figure... Now I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: only as add: my original posted code `plot(iran2, col = as.character(lcols2)); plot(nut_iran2, add=TRUE)` work now (with crop and mask of raster) the same as your (@RobertH) posted solution. However, without coordinate bounding box.

Comment: I added more code to show how to add coordinates if you want to plot the polygons first.